# strtotime() seems bugged with a special date

Tags: php

I'm writing a function which calculates the days between two dates.

Strangely I have a strange behaviour for one special day. Here is a part of my code:

```
$startTimestamp = strtotime('25-10-2014');
$endTimestamp   = strtotime('28-10-2014');

for($i = $startTimestamp; $i <= $endTimestamp; $i = $i + (60 * 60 * 24))
{
    echo date("d-m-Y", $i).'<br />';            
}
```

This example gives me this result:

> 25-10-2014
>
> 26-10-2014
>
> 26-10-2014
>
> 27-10-2014

I don't know why the date "26-10-2014" appears two times.

If I try with another dates like:

```
$startTimestamp = strtotime('25-11-2014');
$endTimestamp   = strtotime('28-11-2014');
```

The result is correct:

> 25-11-2014
>
> 26-11-2014
>
> 27-11-2014
>
> 28-11-2014

Comment: I tried it and get right wariant...

Comment: I guess you're European. Remember: this month starts Winter time.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heure_d%27%C3%A9t%C3%A9
Read about DST. In France time change on 26 october this year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably because of the DST (daylight saving time) in the timezone your PHP is configured to.

This mean, if you jump forward 24h, you'll still be the same day, because the day is 25h long.

Comment: Agreed. Better to let php handle it automatically by usng strtotime("+1 day)instead of doing 60*60*24

Comment: Yeah, he is from France and there is DST switch on 26 october :)

Comment: Perfect. It works by using: `for($i = $startTimestamp; $i <= $endTimestamp; $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i))`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `DateTime` class:

```
$startTime = new DateTime('25-10-2014');
$endTime   = new DateTime('28-10-2014');

do {
    echo $startTime->format('d-m-Y'), PHP_EOL;
} while($startTime->modify('+1 day') <= $endTime);
```

Note that you can use the `<=` operator when comparing DateTime objects. Also the `DateTime::modify()` method is aware of daylight saving time issues. (Note that there is a change in daylight saving time on Oct 26)